# Macro doesn't run same on my PC as it runs on another

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a VBA macro for automating part of my work. It was written on laptop which is based on Russian (date/keyboard) settings.

Somehow when I run it on external PC ( based on German in Austria ) It doesn't perform the same way, it gives me wrong results and error - `'run time error '13' type mismatch'`

```
Sub Proverka()

nm = ActiveSheet.Name
Sheets.Add.Name = "mediana"
Worksheets(nm).Select


n = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 
Summa = 0
Kol = 0

k = 1

For i = 2 To n
    Cells(i, 4) = Replace(Cells(i, 4), " Days", "") 
    If Cells(i, 1) = "Resolved-Issued" And Format(Cells(i, 2), "mmmm") = Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Date), "mmmm") And Format(Cells(i, 2), "yyyy") = Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Date), "yyyy") And Cells(i, 13) = "TFO" Then
        If Cells(i, 5) <> "" Then KolD = DateDiff("d", Cells(i, 3), CDate(Split(Cells(i, 5), "/")(1) & "." & Split(Cells(i, 5), "/")(0) & "." & Split(Cells(i, 5), "/")(2))) 

        KolDV = 0 
        D = CDate(Cells(i, 3)) 
        For i2 = 1 To KolD
            If Format(D, "dddd") = "saturday" Or Format(D, "dddd") = "sunday" Then
                KolDV = KolDV + 1
            End If
            D = DateAdd("d", 1, D)
        Next i2
        Cells(i, 4) = Cells(i, 4) - KolDV
        Worksheets("mediana").Cells(k, 1) = Cells(i, 4)
        k = k + 1
        
    End If
Next i

Cells(n + 2, 1) = "Median " & Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Date), "mmmm")
Cells(n + 3, 1) = "Average " & Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Date), "mmmm")

a = WorksheetFunction.Average(Range(Worksheets("mediana").Cells(1, 1), Worksheets("mediana").Cells(k - 1, 1)))
m = WorksheetFunction.Median(Range(Worksheets("mediana").Cells(1, 1), Worksheets("mediana").Cells(k - 1, 1)))
'Worksheets("mediana").Delete

Cells(n + 2, 4) = m
Cells(n + 3, 4) = a

MsgBox "OK"

End Sub
```

Comment: On what line is the error triggered?

Comment: My initial guess is that it is related to the System Date Format, as per [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dateadd-function): "The format of the return value for DateAdd is determined by Control Panel settings, not by the format that is passed in the date argument.". Basically, the difference between the Date Format in on your Russian-based system and the external German-based system is creating the problem here...

Comment: Use `Weekday(D, vbMonday) >= 6` to check for weekend (Saturday or Sunday).

Comment: Hi Dan, try using Option Explicit and then run it line by line using ctr+alt+i (I use mac, maybe in Windows is different) to catch the error.

Comment: Adding to @Gassz, running line-by-line is initiated by F8 in Windows